# C# - SerialDataReceivedEventHandler executing on second event (first event always skipped)

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, visual-studio-2019, barcode-scanner

I have barcode scanner that is using COM4 port.
Every time I scan something, program will start to read barcodes after second scan.

So, I build a project, try to scan and nothing happends. I try to scan again (in this running project) and it starts working perfectly.

On the top of project I declare port as:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
```

I have a method that defines port:

```
public void ScannerPortSetup()
{
        port.PortName = "COM4";               
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.ReadTimeout = 200;

        try
        {
            port.Open();
            
            if (port.IsOpen == true)
            {
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recieve);
                
             }

            else
            {
                //print not opened
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error on com4: " + e);
        }
 }
```

Method that defines received action:

```
    private void Recieve(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        String recieved_data = port.ReadExisting();
   
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (currentScreenName == ApplicationPages.SkladisteScreen.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("scanned completed:  " + recieved_data);
            }
           

        }); 
    }
```

Again, I do not know why it does not fire on first event, but from second it works perfectly.
It does not matter if I placed i.e. MessageBox inside this.Dispatcher.Invoke() or just above in  Recieve method. Seems like Recieve is not fired first time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please try DataReceived event registration before opening. [SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) And also set RtsEnable to true.

Comment: Not working :( Maybe I am starting ScennerPortSetup() at the wrong time? I am starting it in the MainWindow.xaml.cs,  after MainWindow is lodaded, delegates set and DisplayedPage called as MainFrame.Content

Comment: Could be also a problem with the serial driver. Could you try to use a serial terminal (like HTerm) to check if the first data is received there?

Comment: HTerm showed the same behaviour - first scan is skipped, then it works normally. However, I found out that when I connect device it shows DSR ready. When first scan occurs, nothing happends, but device turns off DSR and scanning works normally. So, it's down to device. I will have to contact manufacturer.